# URI.parse returns nil port for sftp and ftps

Tags: ruby, url-parsing

When I try to parse the following URLs, `URI.parse` returns `nil` for the port:

```
require 'uri'

url = "ftp://example.com"
puts URI.parse(url).port
# => 21

url = "sftp://example.com"
puts URI.parse(url).port
# => nil

url = "ftps://example.com"
puts URI.parse(url).port
# => nil
```

Can someone explain why this works for `ftp`, `http` and `https` but not for `sftp` and `ftps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sftp and ftps aren't sepcified, neither the ports they use.

You can check this in the documentation of URI. Look at the namespace.:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

You will find *ftp, http, https* but **no sftp or ftps**.

Unrecognized URI's like these will be of type ->  **URI::Generic**

By looking into their documentation you will see that they have a default port of nil.:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html

You can try this out yourself by running this:

```
puts URI.parse("sftp://example.com").class
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not supported by default in Ruby -

```
p URI.scheme_list

#=> {"FTP"=>URI::FTP,
     "HTTP"=>URI::HTTP,
     "HTTPS"=>URI::HTTPS,
     "LDAP"=>URI::LDAP,
     "LDAPS"=>URI::LDAPS,
     "MAILTO"=>URI::MailTo}
```

the `sftp` and `ftps` are not represented by any Ruby class.  Hence, default port for them will not be picked automatically.